# Why View.getHeight() returns 0 while measure pass is done on same thread?

Tags: android

I am just a beginner in android development. I was trying to get the height of the view with `View.getHeight()` method immediately after setting its `view.setviaibility (View.VISIBLE)` like

```
View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Int viewHeight=View.getHeight;.   // which returns 0
```

I can understand that we need to wait for the drawing phase for the actual measurements and we need to use `ViewTreeObserver` listeners for getting the size. But my question is I think Android is doing all the measure and layout pass in the same thread. Then when we call `View.SetVisibility()` it will recalculate and do all measuring and layout before executing the next line which is to get height. Then why is it not ready yet?? Is Android deploying other threads for Measuring and laying out??

Am sorry if my question was wrong and too basic since I am just a beginner trying to understand things. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring and laying out is postponed until next layout cycle. That way it doesn't have to perform multiple layout recalculations if you change size/visibility of many views in one code block.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification. Can you please provide more information on how often the layout cycle is executed or any share other documentation about this?? Thanks in advance...